# How can I cast a string to integer in Visual Prolog

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I need to cast the string received from the editControl into a integer, how can I do this?

I try: toInt(String, Int), but this is not enebled for Visual Prolog or i dont know how enable it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it for example with predicate toTerm/2-> :

Int = toTerm(integer, String)